# MS Access ADP Disconnected Recordset Reverts

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003, adp

I have an Microsoft Access 2003 ADP, which uses a bound "main" form with several bound continuous-style subforms.  They all utilize disconnected Recordsets via a helper class.

Several users have noticed the same strange behavior: they add/edit a record in the continuous subform, they leave the record (committing the edit to the Recordset), they lock the computer (Ctrl+Alt+Del), they unlock the computer, they go back to the form, after about 5 seconds it flickers and revert to the original unedited state.

I've been able to reproduce this following the steps above, further, after making a change in my form, bound to a disconnected Recordset, I went to SQL Server and changed a value.  After the lock/unlock computer routine, the form flickers and refreshes, and the NEW value I just entered in SQL Server appears.

It's as if after about 5 seconds, my disconnected Recordset is reconnecting (on it's own) and requerying the Recordset.

I realize I'm not giving a lot of information here, but has anyone encountered an issue with disconnected Recordsets reconnecting and requerying?  Or at least have an ideas of where I could start debugging?

I have the ADP and SQL script to create the database if someone would like to recreate this in their environment.

Here's how I'm creating the disconnected Recordset:

```
Dim cnn                 As ADODB.Connection
Dim stmTest             As ADODB.Stream

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open Application.CurrentProject.AccessConnection.ConnectionString

' Create recordset and disconnect it.
Set mrsTest = New ADODB.Recordset
mrsTest.CursorLocation = adUseClient
mrsTest.Open "SELECT * FROM [tblChild] WHERE ParentID = 1" _
    , cnn _
    , adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
Set mrsTest.ActiveConnection = Nothing

cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing

' Copy recordset to stream in memory.
Set stmTest = New ADODB.Stream
stmTest.Open
mrsTest.Save stmTest, adPersistADTG

' Bind form to disconnected recordset.
Set Me.Recordset = mrsTest

' Open a copy of the recordset from the stream.
Set mrsTest = New ADODB.Recordset
stmTest.Position = 0
mrsTest.Open stmTest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted transaction like processing (Save and Cancel buttons) without
>   the tables being locked, in my multiple user system. For continuous
>   forms in Access to work, they must be bound to a Recordset.

You can use forms/subforms bound to temporary tables to achieve just this effect.

http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=206862

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little bit offtopic, but this is interesting code. I have never thought about working with datasets like this. Is there a particular reason why you use these 'disconnected datasets'?

Comment: I wanted transaction like processing (Save and Cancel buttons) without the tables being locked, in my multiple user system.  For continuous forms in Access to work, they must be bound to a Recordset.

I found many examples of disconnected Recordsets; the above code came from here:

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.databases.ms-access/browse_frm/thread/01753dbca8189eb3